# how to use amp training in Allennlp 2.4.0?

Tags: allennlp

I have learned to use AMP and GA tricks on training model from https://medium.com/ai2-blog/tutorial-training-on-larger-batches-with-less-memory-in-allennlp-1cd2047d92ad,
But it seems not supported in the 2.4.0 ?

File "/root/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/training/util.py", line 217, in create_serialization_dir
f"Value for '{key}' in training configuration does not match that the value in "

Comment: AMP still works with AllenNLP. Your problem likely has some other cause. Can you post the whole error message?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have fixed this error through passing a param (type:"gradient_descent")  for trainer in my config.json.   
However, I cannot find the Gradient_descent_trainer class in allennlp 2.4.0 doc,it really makes me confused.

Comment: The documentation is here: https://docs.allennlp.org/main/api/training/gradient_descent_trainer/

Comment: Thanks a lot, It can be finded in the last version 2.5.1, but cannot be finded in a specific version:2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answer！ @Dirk Groeneveld.
finnally,the correct way to use AMP with allennlp 2.4.0 :

```
"trainer": {
    "type":"gradient_descent",
    "use_amp": true,
    "num_gradient_accumulation_steps": 4,
    "distributed": true,
    ...
    }
```